# How to theme angular material button via theme

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-theming

Hello I would like to theme my angular material theme buttons but I am looking a way to change the border radius, background colour, colour and hover. All I could find so far is to change background colour via this code:

```
$my-app-theme: mat.define-light-theme(

    (color: (

        primary: $my-app-primary,

        accent: $my-app-accent,

        warn: $my-app-warn,

      ),

      typography: $my-typography,

    ));

 

$custom-button-theme: mat.define-light-theme(

  (

    color: (

      primary: $my-app-primary,

      accent: $my-app-secondary

    ),

    background-color: (

      primary: $my-app-primary,

      accent: $my-app-secondary

    )

  )

);

 

@include mat.all-component-themes($my-app-theme);

@include mat.button-theme($custom-button-theme);

@include angular-material-typography($my-typography);
```

Thanks!